# onLocationChanged is not called automatically

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

I have a problem with onLocationChanged event in Android. Here's the triggering:

```
case R.id.start: {
    Points.add(overlay.getMyLocation()); // Points' type is ArrayList<GeoPoint>
    mgr.requestLocationUpdates(best, 0, 3, locationListener);
    }
    break;
```

And here's the onLocationChanged method:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    i++;
    Points.add(overlay.getMyLocation());
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(Points.get(i-1), Points.get(i));
    map.getOverlays().add(mapOverlay); //does the drawing
    mMapController.animateTo(Points.get(i));
}
```

So, onLocationChanged is called only once and only after I press "start". It's supposed to be called automatically every time the location has changed, right? In my case, it's not.
Please help me.

Comment: Have you added the permission to use the location service to the manifest like this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`?

Comment: Of course, here's my permission section:   <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Although it is very late but I hope this comment can help someone else, look at this link: http://www.lengrand.fr/2013/10/onlocationchanged-is-never-called-on-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem seems to be solved.
In onCreate, I added:

```
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
best = mgr.getBestProvider(crit, false);
mgr.requestLocationUpdates(best, 0, 1, locationListener);
```

onLocationChanged now looks like that:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    i++;
    nextPoint = overlay.getMyLocation();
    latitude = nextPoint.getLatitudeE6();
    longtitude = nextPoint.getLongitudeE6();
    lastPoint = new GeoPoint((int) latitude, (int) longtitude);
    Points.add(lastPoint);
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(Points.get(i - 1), Points.get(i));
    map.getOverlays().add(mapOverlay);
    mMapController.animateTo(Points.get(i));
    nextPoint = null;
    lastPoint = null;
}
```

Also, very important methods:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mgr.requestLocationUpdates(best, 10000, 1, locationListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mgr.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}
```

And also some new permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` is not necessary if you use `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. Just for you to know ;)

Comment: @lomza, what is the difference?

Comment: @gumuruh, because `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` includes WiFi, cell and GPS location and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` includes just cell and WiFi. So the first permission basically includes the second one.

Comment: @lomza, that's good clarification. THanks for it. I just know it from you. :D

Comment: what is `best` , `mgr` and `locationListener` ?

Comment: @RaviVaniya `mgr` is the LocationManager which you can obtain using `locationManager = (LocationManager) requireContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` - `locationListener` is your implementation of the Android `LocationListener` interface and `best` is a `String` containing the name of the provider which best meets the criteria you passed.