# Android Google Maps API v2 Center Zoom

Tags: java, android, google-maps, zooming, google-maps-android-api-2

I have Google Maps set up with my application and can view the map with a blue dot indicating my location on the map, however everything I have tried to centre and zoom in on that location automatically does not seem to work.

When I press the target icon in the top right the camera view zooms in to my location which is what I want it to do automatically.

I have tried the following:

```
LatLng latlngPos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())

myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlngPos));
myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```

And also tried

```
myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlngPos, 15));
```

Yet neither seem to be working. I have these lines of code in onLocationChanged as shown in a tutorial I have followed. I have attempted different suggestions from similar questions on here also and it still seems to be zoomed out, yet highlighting my current location in the correct position by a blue dot on the map.

Have I missed something obvious? Thanks

Edit: Entire activity:-

```
public class FindBankActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap myMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Make sure Google Play Services available
    if(isGooglePlay()){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_bank);
        setUpMap();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.find_bank, menu);

    return true;
}

public boolean isGooglePlay() {

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return(true);
    }
    else
    {
        ((Dialog) GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 15)).show();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return(false);
}

public void setUpMap() {

    if(myMap == null) {

        myMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


        if(myMap != null) {
            //Initiate map  

            myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            String provider = lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

            if(provider == null) {
                onProviderDisabled(provider);
            }

            Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(loc == null) {

                LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        double lat = location.getLatitude();
                        double lng = location.getLongitude();

                        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat,lng);

                        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 15));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                            int status, Bundle extras) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                };

                lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, locListener);

            }

                if(loc != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(loc);
                }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    //Get the location
    LatLng latlngPos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


    //Display on the map and zoom in 
//      myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlngPos));
//      myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlngPos, 15));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to add the MAP-UI Settings

```
myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks but I already have the manual Zoom controls enabled so I can click the + or - to zoom in/out. I want it to automatically zoom into my location when the activity starts.

Comment: Past your entire activity please, I've used Google Maps quite a bit and Zooming I seem to know a lot about. The code you pasted in your question seems correct. So please paste your entire activity so I can see how you're implementing it.

Comment: @rjc I see you've put the above code inside `onLocationChanged`. Why? If you want to move it automatically, keep it outside the LocationListener. From what it seems, are you sure the onLocationChanged is being called? Have you tested it? Try putting a `Toast` inside onLocationChanged() and see if it displays.

Comment: @rjc also see this post if `onLocationChanged` is not called: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447861/onlocationchanged-is-not-called-automatically

Answer (score 0):

You have followed a wrong tutorial. If you want to get updates on blue dot location changes, use [`OnMyLocationChangeListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener) with your `GoogleMap` object instead of `LocationManager`.

These methods can return different results because `GoogleMap` uses fused location provider and `LocationManager` only raw GPS or network provider.

If you are worried about `OnMyLocationChangeListener` being deprecated, see [my monologue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971309/google-maps-android-api-v2-apis-related-to-my-location-deprecated-why).